# matplotlib plt.scatter showing wrong x axis data

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization, visualization

I have a json

```
[
  {
    "price": 649000,
    "bedrooms": 3,
    "bathrooms": 2.0,
    "yr_built": 1984,
    "sqft_lot": 3250.0,
    "zpid": 15767255,
    "address": "7036 Overlook Dr"
  },
  {
    "price": 649000,
    "bedrooms": 3,
    "bathrooms": 2.0,
    "yr_built": 1984,
    "sqft_lot": 3250.0,
    "zpid": 15767255,
    "address": "7036 Overlook Dr"
  },
]

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


data = pd.read_json(json.dumps(json_data))
plt.scatter(data.price, data.sqft_lot)
```

Why is it that for x-axis `data.price` the number ranges are only showing from 1-4 and not the actual price themselves?

[image]

Comment: There is a 1e-6 in the bottom right hand corner

Answer (score 1):

The x axis actually shows the correct price values, but the axis is set to *scientific* notation. You can turn this notation on or off with [**`matplotlib.pyplot.ticklabel_format`**](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ticklabel_format.html):

#### OFF

```
plt.ticklabel_format(axis = 'x', style = 'plain')
```

[image]

#### ON

```
plt.ticklabel_format(axis = 'x', style = 'scientific', scilimits = (0, 0))
```

[image]